# Can bitbake include/require a file based on a variable?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

With bitbake, I'd like to be able to include/require a different file based on a variable, i.e.

require ${somevar}

From everything I've read this doesn't work directly, but maybe there's a solution for my specific use case.  I'm using OECore and would like to have one image recipe that includes a group of settings located in another file based on something like the MACHINE.  So rather than having to do this:

```
SETTING_A_machine1 = "..."
SETTING_B_machine1 = "..."
SETTING_C_machine1 = "..."
SETTING_D_machine1 = "..."
...
SETTING_A_machine2 = "..."
SETTING_B_machine2 = "..."
SETTING_C_machine2 = "..."
SETTING_D_machine2 = "..."
...
```

I'd like to be able to do something equivalent to this:

```
require include/${MACHINE}.inc
```

include/machine1.inc

```
SETTING_A = "..."
SETTING_B = "..."
SETTING_C = "..."
SETTING_D = "..."
```

include/machine2.inc

```
SETTING_A = "..."
SETTING_B = "..."
SETTING_C = "..."
SETTING_D = "..."
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yocto supports machine override, could you give the following a try:

```
your-image-recipe.bb
include/machine1/common.inc
include/machine2/common.inc
```

Then in your-image-recipe.bb, you have:

```
require include/common.inc
```

Comment: This won't work, overrides work for SRC_URI but not include paths like this. The reason is there is no need for this to work, require include/${MACHINE}.inc will work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually tried this?

require include/${MACHINE}.inc

should just work. If you look at bitbake.conf, this is how the machine configuration files are included in the first place! You just need to be aware that this implies immediate variable expansion so if you reference ${FOO} here, then later in the file change FOO, it won't be reflected in the file which is included.